# HTML5 Web SQL Database for non compatible browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really like sql-database in HTML5, but so far only [Opera and Webkit browsers support this feature](http://html5demos.com/). Are there any javascript libraries out there that replicate this feature or provide something close to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, without some sort of API for secure client-side data storage, there's not much a Javascript library can do. There are always cookies, but storage is limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been researching and found a few

[JSormDB](http://jsorm.com/wiki/Jsormdb)

[XBSDB](http://xbsdb.org/index.html)

[TaffyDB](http://taffydb.com/index.cfm)

[JSINQ](http://jsinq.codeplex.com/documentation)

[TrimQuery](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/TrimQuery)

[AMASS](http://codinginparadise.org/weblog/2005/10/amass-ajax-massive-storage-system.html)

also relevant [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-database-in-browser) and [this](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2009/04/20/javascriptdb-perseveres-new-high-performance-storage-engine/). Hope this helps out someone.